# How to order cells in lane in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, ordering

It is very easy to order cell values in column, but how can I order many values in a lane?

I would like to avoid to

1. copy
2. paste/trasponse
3. order
4. copy
5. paste/trasponse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Home tab - editing, open `Sort & Filter` and select `custom sort`.

[image]
Select options and chose `Sort Left to Right`

This may vary to Office versions, but the steps are similar.
If you give me your version of Office, I will update my answer with the steps accordingly.

Comment: I use Office 2007 and I find where to set this options